# Amend form content on Ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

**Update**

I just learnt that is not possible to use cookie and session as both mobile App and website on totally different servers using different platforms

---

I'm trying to submit the following form (using Ajax):

```
<form action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&task=user.login'); ?>" method="post">

    <fieldset>
        <?php foreach ($this->form->getFieldset('credentials') as $field): ?>
            <?php if (!$field->hidden): ?>
                <div class="login-fields"><?php echo $field->label; ?>
                <?php echo $field->input; ?></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php if (JPluginHelper::isEnabled('system', 'remember')) : ?>
        <div class="login-fields">
            <label id="remember-lbl" for="remember"><?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_REMEMBER_ME') ?></label>
            <input id="remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" class="inputbox" value="yes"  alt="<?php echo JText::_('JGLOBAL_REMEMBER_ME') ?>" />
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="submit" class="button"><?php echo JText::_('JLOGIN'); ?></button>
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo base64_encode($this->params->get('login_redirect_url', $this->form->getValue('return'))); ?>" />
        <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

From different domain. The following is working for me:

```
    $.ajax(
{
type:"POST", 
url:"https://192.168.12.103/components/com_users/views/login/tmpl/default_login.php?callback=?", 
data:$('form').serialize(),
success: function(data){
alert("successful");
}
}
);
```

The problem is I do not want the form to work in its current logic. That is the current form (login to website form), retrieve credentials from website login page and validate ... etc. What I need to amend is to pass the credentials to the form using my Ajax request and make the form use those credentials.

Is that possible without changing the form itself?
If no, how to create similar form with this minor tweak?

My eventual objective, is to allow login from Mobile App to the website behind the scene (without going through website login page).

Comment: didnt get it, what you actually want ?

Comment: @hawk Off topic! Which framework are you using

Comment: Huh? You want to change the form on the fly? Why not just programatically create it to start with? Regardless, off topic.

Comment: @MurtazaHussain What I want is to allow mobile App users to login website without being prompted to insert their credentials. They are already verified when they logged in to the mobile App. However, since App and Website are totally different platforms, I found the easiest way to do it is to do another login (behind the scene). My understanding is when the user clicks on login button on the website, the above form will be submitted. So I want to submit that form automatically.

Comment: simply put a cookie or create a session.

Comment: @RaheelKhan Mobile App developed in JavaScript on Appery platform. Website on Joomla. (both have different DB's but same data - login information)

Comment: @DylanGattey So you think creating another form that reads the credentials from Ajax request is possible and the way to go? Sorry if this sounds naive but I'm new to PHP

Comment: @MurtazaHussain Not sure how to do that. would you elaborate?

Comment: have a look at this http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp and http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp

Comment: @MurtazaHussain Thanks, I had a look. So I assume that I need to create session at the mobile App, and when navigate to the website, the session variables will be retrieved at the beginning of login page. How to use the variables (username/password) to login automatically to the website?

Comment: The whole idea of session is not to Login again, sessions are created on servers and hence once session is created you dont need to login again, until and unless session is destroyed on server or have expired